# Finding limit of this $\sin(x)\cos(\frac{1}{x-\pi})$: how to go about it?

Tags: limits

How do I go about finding the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to \pi}  = \sin(x)\cos(\frac{1}{x-\pi})$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the squeeze theorem?  If so, I'd point out that $-1\leq\cos(1/(x-\pi))\leq 1$, for all $x\neq\pi$.

Comment: @AustinC i have heard of it but we have not learned it yet

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{x\to\pi} \sin x \cos\frac{1}{x-\pi} =0 $$ since $\cos\frac{1}{x-\pi}$ is bounded.

Comment: what do you mean by "is bounded"?

Comment: Bounded meaning any values of cosine will be in between 0 and 1

Answer (score 0):

Remember $$\lim_{x\to\pi} \sin (x) =0 $$
Also the other part is bounded.It gives the result.We should remember that $\sin\pi =0$.

Comment: please use \sin(x) and \lim_{x\to \pi}$